# Организация преобразования request dto в entity

Tags: архитектура, dto, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня есть request dto определенной entity1. Оно содержит поле anotherEntityId, которое содержит id entity2 из другой таблицы. Но в entity1 у меня вместо этого находится поле anotherEntity типа entity2(то есть мне нужно найти нужную entity2 по ее id из request dto и засетить ее в entity1). У меня есть сервисный слой, а так же dto сервис, который занимается маппингом дто в ентити и обратно. Где мне нужно делать это присваивание? В дто сервисе или в основном сервисе? ChatGpt говорит что такая логика не должна находится в дто сервисе, но и делать мой дто сервис неполностью функциональным(возвращающим только частично заполненную entity) тоже не очень. Как поступить в данном вопросе? Где разместить эту логику?